# Alternate visual button while showing tabbed div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to alternate a list item when it is clicked to show it is the current active list item?  It would be ideal if this could be done in bootstrap some how(perused bootstrap manual to no avail), in button form, so that you click on a button and it is highlighted while the div is shown.  Here is a working example, WITHOUT the indication of the active div :

http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/opdzhzzz/2/

Attached is an image of desired result 
[image]

Code :

```
<ul id="ul-menu-list">
    <li id="tabone">How it Works</li>
    <li id="tabtwo">Features</li>
    <li id="tabthree">FAQ</li>
</ul>
<di id="box-one" class="box">Tab one</di>
<di id="box-two" class="box">Tab two</di>
<di id="box-three" class="box">Tab three</di>

<script>
$("#ul-menu-list li").click(function () {
    $('.box').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this...

Add a new class to the CSS for the "active" item:

```
.red { background: red; }
```

Then adjust the jQuery to apply the class:

```
$("#ul-menu-list li").click(function () {
    $("#ul-menu-list li").removeClass('red'); /* removes any existing red */
    $(this).addClass('red'); /* adds red to clicked item */
    $('.box').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

[Updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/opdzhzzz/143/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes... in fact, the way you are using your jQuery will help you.  All you need to do is remove a "selected" class from all LI when clicked.  Then add the class back to the one that was selected.

```
$("#ul-menu-list li").click(function () {
    $( '#ul-menu-list li' ).removeClass( 'selected' );
    $( this ).addClass( 'selected' );
    $('.box').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

Then set a style for the 'selected' class.  And, you can also manually add this class to the first LI element to allow for the first visible tab to have this background:

```
.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/opdzhzzz/142/

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#ul-menu-list li").click(function () {
    $("#ul-menu-list li").removeClass('active'); /* remove 'active' class from all li's */
    $(this).addClass('active'); /* add active class to clicked li */
    $('.box').hide().eq($(this).index()).show();
});
```

```css
#ul-menu-list li.active {
   background: green; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="ul-menu-list">
    <li id="tabone" class="active">How it Works</li>
    <li id="tabtwo">Features</li>
    <li id="tabthree">FAQ</li>
</ul>
<di id="box-one" class="box">Tab one</di>
<di id="box-two" class="box">Tab two</di>
<di id="box-three" class="box">Tab three</di>
```

Comment: So one question before i choose as best answer(posted first).  Could I change a bootstraps buttons class with the $(this).addClass('active'); being as such the following : $(this).addClass('btn btn.primary'); to change the color of a bootstrap button as its clicked?

Comment: Yes, of course you can. Though it would be: `$(this).addClass('btn btn-primary')`

Comment: I am really sorry, didn't realize another person had already answered

Comment: Don't worry about it. That's the nature of SO :)